# Detecting click on and outside of PopupButton in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with PopupButton in WPF. 
When I press it once the popup appears with some items to select (ElementTreeControl). After i press the same PopupButton it should close - yet it closes and opens again.
I solved that and it was working but when i click outside of this control and it closes (StayOpen = false) I have problem with reopening it again - need to press PopupButton two times.

Is there some property or workaround on how to detect when the control was pressed and when it was area outside of it?

I want the PopupButton to be:

When closed:

- opens with one click

When open:

- closed with 2nd click on popupButton
- closed with click on the outside area

Popup button click action:

```
private Popup rtWindowBoundsPopup;

private async void ButtonClickAsync(object pmSender, RoutedEventArgs pmE)
{
    if (pmSender is PopupButton lcButton)
    {
        if (lcButton.Tag is StarElement lcStarElement)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DatabaseName))
            {
                lcStarElement = await rtStarHelper.AssureMetaData(lcStarElement, DatabaseName);
            }
            else
            {
                StarDim lcStarDim = rtStarHelper.GetDimFromDimId(lcStarElement.Dim.DimId, true);
                lcStarElement.Dim = await rtStarHelper.AssureMetaData(lcStarDim);
            }
            ShowTreeViewPopup(lcButton, lcStarElement);
        }
    }
}


private void ShowTreeViewPopup(PopupButton pmButton, StarElement pmStarElement)
 {
     ElementTreeControl lcElementTreeControl;
     if (rtWindowBoundsPopup == null)
     {
         rtWindowBoundsPopup = new Popup();// { IsLightDismissEnabled = true };
        rtWindowBoundsPopup.Opened += WindowBoundsPopupOpened;
     }

     if (rtWindowBoundsPopup.Child is ElementTreeControl lcTreeControl)
     {
         lcElementTreeControl = lcTreeControl;
         lcElementTreeControl.HideAddionalCols();
     }
     else
     {
         lcElementTreeControl = new ElementTreeControl { Tag = pmButton };
         rtWindowBoundsPopup.Child = lcElementTreeControl;
         lcElementTreeControl.SelectionChanged += PopupListBoxSelectionChangedAsync;
     }

     Point lcPoint = UiHelper.CalcOffsets(pmButton);
     Rect lcCurrentwindowbounds = CurrentWindow.RestoreBounds;
     if (lcPoint.Y < lcCurrentwindowbounds.Height / 2)
     {
         lcElementTreeControl.MaxHeight = lcCurrentwindowbounds.Height - lcPoint.Y - pmButton.ActualHeight;
     }
     else
     {
         lcElementTreeControl.MaxHeight = lcPoint.Y - pmButton.ActualHeight;
     }
     lcElementTreeControl.Width = Math.Max(pmButton.ActualWidth, 400);
     lcElementTreeControl.MaxWidth = lcCurrentwindowbounds.Width;
     lcElementTreeControl.MinHeight = 150;
     lcElementTreeControl.Init(rtStarCube, pmStarElement, rtStarHelper);
     lcElementTreeControl.CaptionColWidth = lcElementTreeControl.Width;
     rtWindowBoundsPopup.PlacementTarget = pmButton;
     rtWindowBoundsPopup.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
     rtWindowBoundsPopup.StaysOpen = false;//false;
     rtWindowBoundsPopup.Closed -= WindowBoundsPopupOnClosed;
     rtWindowBoundsPopup.Closed += WindowBoundsPopupOnClosed;

     rtWindowBoundsPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

In WindowBoundsPopupOnClosed nothing happens, i have tried to make it work there but didn't menage to do so.

Comment: Why can't you try to capture a click event in the view where the popup is placed. So the event gets fired when you click outside the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you actually close the `Popup`? I only see you setting `IsOpen` to `true`. Current behavior: the first click on `PopupButton` will open the `Popup`. Now because `StaysOpen` is set to `false`, clicking the button (which is outside the `Popup`) a second time will close the `Popup`, as the `popup` has lost focus, since it is moved from `Popup` to the `PopupButton`. `IsOpen` returns now `false`. This second click then invokes the event handler `ButtonClickAsync` which sets `IsOpen` back to true again, which reopens the `Popup`.

Your code is too complicated, because you are using C# instead of XAML.

The `PopupButton` should be a `ToggleButton` or based on it.

```
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="PopupButton" />
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PopupButton, Path=IsChecked}">
      <ElementTreeControl Tag="pmButton" />
    </Popup>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

---

### Using `EventTrigger`

An alternative approach is to use `EventTrigger`. This can be easier in situations, where you don't have access to the triggering control 'e.g., the `PopupButton`, as it might be defined out of scope e.g inside some other template. This example still assumes that `PopupButton` is derived from `ToggleButton`:

**The `Window`, which hosts the `Popup`**
(The `ToggleButton`, which opens/closes the `Popup`, is defined in a separate control `ControlWithPopupButton`, see below)

```
<Window>
  <Window.Triggers>

    <!-- 
      EventTriggers must be defined in the scope of the Popup "RtWindowBoundsPopup" 
      and in the routing path of the raised event.
    -->
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked" 
                  Sourcename="PopupButton">      
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RtWindowBoundsPopup"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
                                          Duration="0">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked" 
                  Sourcename="PopupButton">      
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RtWindowBoundsPopup"
                                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen"
                                          Duration="0">
            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="True" />
          </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Window.Triggers>

  <StackPanel>
    <ControlWithPopupButton />
    <Popup x:Name="RtWindowBoundsPopup">
      <ElementTreeControl Tag="pmButton" />
    </Popup>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**The UserControl, which contains the `PopupButton`**

```
<ControlWithPopupButton>

  <!-- 
    PopupButton must derive from ToggleButton
    or raise both Routed Events ToggleButon.Check and ToggleButton.Unchecked. 
  -->
  <PopupButton x:Name="PopupButton" />
</ControlWithPopupButton>
```

### Remarks

Then methods like `ElementTreeControl.Init`, should be called from the `ElementTreeControl.Loaded` event handler inside the `ElementTreeControl` class. I don't now what `StarElement` is, but it should bind to a `DependencyProperty` of `ElementTreeControl`. I don't have enough context, but I guess you should add an `override` of `ElementTreeControl.OnSelectionChanged`, so that you can move the code of `PopupListBoxSelectionChangedAsync` to the `ElementTreeControl`.

---

Comment: Hello! This is from legacy code and that is why it is so complicated. The popupButton is launched from other control but I will try to adapt what you said with toggleButton.

The popup is closed because of property StaysOpen set to false and also on selection changed event - there is IsOpen set to false.

Comment: You can still bind to the button, no matter where it is defined (almost). You can also use an `EventTrigger`. I updated my question to show how to achieve toggling the `Popup` (based on a `ToggleButton` click) using an ÈventTrigger`. This might be the best solution in your scenario.